# I'm having problem dismissing a modal view when calling it inside a navigation bar with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, binding, navigation, swiftui

At tap "Show Modal" button in navigation bar, the modal is shown.
But, when "Dismiss" button is tapped, the modal never is showed.
If the modal is swiped, the error don't occurr.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Show Modal") {

                    self.showModal = true
                    })
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
            Modal()
        }
    }
}

struct Modal: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Modal")
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Dismiss") {
                    self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to toggle off the `showModal` state. Something like this will work. I merged both views to demonstrate quickly

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModal = false
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Show Modal") {

                    self.showModal.toggle()
                    })
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
            NavigationView {
                Text("Modal")
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Dismiss") {
                        self.showModal.toggle()
                        self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for me, but just add `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode` in both views.

Comment: You need to toggle (set showModal to false) as well because otherwise it will not hide